# Calculus Question (Simple)

Tags: calculus

Assume that $f'(x)= g'(x)$ with $f(1) = -5$ and $g(x) = -x*f(x)$. Then $f(x) =....$

- a) $g(x) - 10x - 10$
- b) $g'(x) -10$
- c) $g(x) -10x$
- d)$ g(x) - x$
- e) $g(x) - 10$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: (Uninteresting approach) Plug in all the possibile $f$ given and find which one solves the system.

Hint 2: by the product rule:
$$g'(x)=-f(x)-xf'(x).$$
Now plug $g'=f'$ into this equation and solve the ODE.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just realised this a minute after I posted - I was on the 2nd step.

Answer (score 0):

Two functions which are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ (any interval would do) differ by …